# How to wait for subview layout settle down after the initial viewDidLoad cycle?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController`, I made an zoomableImageView by embedding a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`.

```
class ZoomableImageView: UIScrollView {
    // public so that delegate can access
    public let imageView: UIImageView = {

        let _imageView = UIImageView()
        _imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return _imageView

    } ()



     // this method will be called multiple times to display different images
    public func setImage(image: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = image

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

        self.contentSize = image.size

        // gw: not working here, too early
        setZoomScale()

    }

    func setZoomScale() {


        let imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size

        let scrollViewSize = self.bounds.size
        let widthScale = scrollViewSize.width / imageViewSize.width
        let heightScale = scrollViewSize.height / imageViewSize.height

        print("gw: imageViewSize: \(imageViewSize), scrollViewSize: \(scrollViewSize)")

        self.minimumZoomScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        self.maximumZoomScale = 1.2 // allow maxmum 120% of original image size

        // set initial zoom to fit the longer side (longer side ==> smaller scale)
        zoomScale = minimumZoomScale


    }

}
```

Each time I change the `UIImage` of the image view, I want to wait for the `UIImageView`'s bound size to settle down, before I can use it to calculate a scale factor for zooming in `UIScrollView`.

**Question**: What is the appropriate place to put `setZoomScale()`? I put it right before exiting the `setImage` method, but the `imageView.bounds.size` is not correct in my print statement. Note that it needs to be triggered each time the image changes, not just the initial view loading stage.

I also tried to put `setZoomScale` in ViewController's `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but I have addtional question here: is `viewWillLayoutSubviews` only called once at view initialization stage? Can I force trigger it using `setNeedsLayout`? (which I tried, but not re-triggering viewWillLayoutSubviews)

Comment: Have you tried putting `setZoomScale()` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`?

Comment: I already put set image inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`, can I wrap two layers ?

Comment: Yes you can. It would probably solve the problem I guess.

Comment: Actually not real sure what the issue is.  I added the missing code to make this work and running on an iPad in playground it is working well.  Fitting nicely then allowing a scale.   Are you using constraints on the ZoomImageView that may not be laid out on first pass.  I changed a few things and added what i needed and it seems to be working find

Comment: @RickyMo Yes It did solve the problem. You can put this as answer and I ll mark it

Comment: @agibson007 Thanks for trying out in code. The occurence of issue is intermittent. It happens in my actual application which has a bit more complexity. It may not be happening if pull out alone.

Comment: Added explanation in answer.

Comment: I agree with the answer however I will add that in a recent application one of the test devices behaved very weird in using DispatchQueue to effectively run after this stuff. I know because that’s what I tried first. What worked best for me is setting the imageview/contentview frame to be that of the min and then just set a max scale factor. My purpose was exactly what you do here and I had to restore state on previous images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As any change to UI elements dispatch the operation to the main dispatch queue, you can put your code in `DispathQueue.main.async{}` to make sure it run after the UI change is done.

```
public func setImage(image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

    self.contentSize = image.size

    // gw: not working here, too early
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
         self.setZoomScale()
    }
}
```